# Easy file transfer for big files?

Tags: internet, file-transfer, p2p

I need to transfer a big file (2.4 GB) to another person over internet. The recipient doesn't want to (or can't?) install any new software to the PC.

I googled what are the preferred methods nowadays for this purpose, and I was lead to two quite interesting sounding free open-source services: file.pizza, instant.io and squidl.ink. All three seem to work through mere browsers, not needing any accounts and the transfer seems to happen between the source and recipient directly, without e.g. first having to upload the file to some server (which has restrictions how big the file can be) from which the recipient downloads it etc.

However, I just don't seem to get those three services to work. I am using the Firefox browser with them as suggested. instant.io doesn't really go anywhere when I add the file, while file.pizza and squidl.ink just seem to process the file seemingly forever, without giving any feedback if they are really doing anything or is the processing of the file progressing at all. I tried also with a bit smaller 400MB compressed file but didn't have any better success. With a small file of 4MB of size, file and squidl did process it quickly.

Any idea if those aforementioned services should work (also with big files), how long does it normally take for them to process big files, and are there any alternatives that actually work?

Comment: I use google drive in my gmail account, once uploaded you can send a link to download via email. Any file that size will require time to upload it anywhere, as this is limited by your isp's upload bandwidth you are paying for.

Comment: That fits within DropBox as well. These are the easiest ways to do this.

Comment: Hmm maybe you guys are right. Apparently Google Drive and DropBox size is quite enough for that, and the recipient can download them with his web browser...

Comment: I am still interested to know if those services like file.pizza or squidl.ink are supposed to work, as the idea that you can send the file directly without a middleman sounds good, and file.pizza also uses p2p protocol so many people can download and upload at the same time the same file (=many recipients at the same time)

Comment: If it is you and another person, set up the service shared between two. Works fine. I have a DropBox Account of my own plus another that up to a dozen people are authorized to access and get documents.  Document in and then document out

Comment: "Send the file directly".. do you understand what you are asking?  This means that your PC would need to host and send the file over and over and over.. do you really want this?  Have you looked into torrents?

Comment: In this case it was only to one recipient, and I would have preferred a method where there is no third-party server in the middle hosting the file (if for no other reason that I do not want anyone else, even google, to have hold of that file, except the intended recipient). Ok so I 7-zip compressed the file with a strong and very long password, in case google tries to decrypt it on their server. :)

Comment: file.pizza seems to have a good idea, a peer-to-peer delivery over internet straight from you to the recipient, even if the transfer is initiated through a hosted web service.

And if there are several recipients like you suggested, then they will also upload parts of the file to each other, normal stuff for p2p networks. So you are not the only uploader, only the primary one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So like some suggested, just using GoogleDrive or DropBox for this particular case was the easiest and most straightforward solution, as I had a free GD account already (which I really never used before) and their size limit was not as low as I believed it would be.

However, I am still interested in the technology and idea behind those services like file.pizza, instant.io and squidl.ink, which to me basically seems like "torrent without additional client software" (besides your browser). And since they use browsers and at least file.pizza is using mere javascript, apparently they are also quite platform agnostic and should work from any platform that can use a web browser with javascript.

The only problem was, I couldn't get any of those three to work, at least in my case. Too bad.